# jQuery code not working in Firefox OS simulator

Tags: jquery, firefox-os

Me and some of my friends wrote some code in jquery for a simple app. But when we tried to run it in the Firefox OS simulator, we got only the part without any jquery code.

This is our code:

```
<h1>D-BAG</h1> 
<body>
<h2><div id="home" class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-2x" style="border: #800000"></div></h2>
    <div id="start"><div class="fa fa-power-off fa-1x">--START</div><br><br><div class="fa fa-plus fa-1x">--CREATE</div></div>

        <script src="assets\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.js" type="text/jscript></script>
        <script src="assets\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js" type="text/jscript></script>
        <script src="assets\jquery.js" type="text/jscript></script>
        <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#home").click(function(){
                $("#start").slideToggle("slow");
                });
        });
        </script>
</body>
```

When we run it, we dont get anything on the screen except "D-BAG"

Comment: Just a note: your `<h1>` tag should be inside your `<body>`. Everything should either be in the `<head>` (not visible) or the `<body>` (visible)

Comment: You're also not closing quotes in some of your tags. But I'm not seeing your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/t5gptgdk/. Would you mind posting your CSS? I'm under the impression that the other elements might be hidden with CSS based off of your JS

Comment: Shouldn't jquery be the first referenced javascript include? Moreover, the mime type is `text/javascript`. You wrote `text/jscript` instead.